# Transfer file colors settings to another project

Tags: phpstorm

How can I transfer **File Colors** settings in other project?

I've tried doing it via `File | Export Settings...` but there is no "File Colors" entry...

Comment: What "Color File" you mean exactly? Screenshots please.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/jrz7p.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**File Colors** are project-specific setting and not IDE-wide -- they cannot be exported via `File | Export Settings...`.

- **Shared File Colors** are saved in `YourProject/.idea/fileColors.xml` file and can be shared with other people via VCS (just copy-paste that file into another project/computer).
- **Local File Colors** are saved together with other developer-specific settings in `YourProject/.idea/workspace.xml` and are not meant to be shared with others.

---

The **scopes** (the left column of that list on your screenshot):

- **Shared scopes** are stored in individual files in `YourProject/.idea/scopes/` folder.
- **Local (private) scopes** are shared together with other developer-specific settings in `YourProject/.idea/workspace.xml` file.

Comment: YourProject/.idea/fileColors.xml has only Name and Color but where file path for this? ;]

Comment: I assume by "file path" you mean **scopes** (the left column of that list on your screenshot). If that's so -- all **shared scopes** are stored in individual files in `.idea/scopes/` folder. All **local (private) scopes** are shared together with other developer-specific settings in `.idea/workspace.xml` file.

Comment: Very interest but .idea\scopes has one **file scope_settings** only and this file identical in all projects.

Comment: 1) Make sure that such scopes are "shared" and 2) Try closing IDE (or project at least) -- some files may only be saved when project gets closed. I have here in my special test project 1 private and 4 shared scopes and files are there (4 files + scope_settings.xml)

Comment: I resolve IT! Need copy fileColors.xml for colors. Need sharing all Scopes via IDE. Need copy all files .idea\scopes and replace(!) file[name_project]  on file[*] in all files.

Comment: *"and replace(!) `file[name_project]` on `file[*]` in all files."* Possibly better is to replace `file[name_project]:` by just `file:` (in original project, of course) -- for PhpStorm project I see no need for the `[*]` part. But if it works for you then it's all good.